# How to use NeoVim as a pager?

Tags: neovim, pager

I tried `export PAGER="nvim -R"`, however it does not work for man page, so I `export MANPAGER="nvim -c 'set ft=man' -"` again, it works. However it still does not work for git log, it looks like below:

[image]

Is there any way to solve all problems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For git, you may want to use the the following configuration:

`git config --global core.pager "nvim -R"`

It can be a good idea to tell git to disable colors as it would conflict with neovim colors:

`git config --global color.pager no`

This second command fix the bug of your screenshot

Comment: As stated in the [official `git-config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), the configuration option to set the text viewer is `core.pager` rather than `core.page`.

Comment: @R.Morales, you are right, I have fixed this. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

https://neovim.io/doc/user/filetype.html#ft-man-plugin
To use Nvim as a manpager:

> ```
> export MANPAGER='nvim +Man!'
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using neovim and vim with `update-alternatives`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi /usr/bin/nvim 60
sudo update-alternatives --config vi
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vim vim /usr/bin/nvim 60
sudo update-alternatives --config vim
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/nvim 60
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

the configuration of `update-alternatives` print:

```
  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/nvim        60        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/nvim        60        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
```

then exporting `MANPAGER`:

```
export MANPAGER="/bin/sh -c \"col -b | vim -c 'set ft=man ts=8 nomod nolist nonu noma' -\""
```

Answer (score 1):

[nvimpager](https://github.com/lucc/nvimpager) is an alternative solution.

`export PAGER=nvimpager`.

`export MANPAGER=nvimpager`.

`git config --global color.pager no`.

`git config --global core.pager nvimpager`.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues setting up `nvim` as `MANPAGER` because the following error appeared every time I tried to open a `man` page (such as `man man`):

```
fuse: mount failed: Permission denied

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option.
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
man: command exited with status 127: sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/{ N; /^[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*$/D; }' | LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page man(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page man(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=man(1) nvim -c set ft=man -
```

Looking for alternatives, which I could not find, I ended up with the following `zsh` function and alias:

```
function my_man {
    $EDITOR +"Man $1|on"
}
alias man="my_man"
```

You need to activate a `vim` plugin that comes shipped with `vim` and `nvim` by adding the following line to your `.vimrc`:

```
runtime! ftplugin/man.vim
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!